# Exchange 2010, import a renewed cert without creating a new CSR?

Tags: exchange, certificate

I renewed my certificate for my exchange 2010 box and I want to put the newest cert that I downloaded cer file) on the server.  But it appears the only way to put in the renewed certificate is to complete a new CSR, which I have no interest in doing.  Is there an easy way to pop this new cert in?

Answer (score 1):

certreq -accept should do the trick, have a look at
[this Micrisoft KB article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725793%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of file is it?

Could you add the cert through IIS?

Or what about "Import-ExchangeCertificate" Cmdlet for the Management Shell? If you got a pfx, you should be able to import through both the Management Shell and the Management Console.

Answer (score 0):

I received the renewed certificate in .crt and .p7b files format (without generating a CSR on Exchange). I don't have pfx.